# Git mvnw command results in ConnectException

Tags: git, maven, proxy

I am trying to get the following Project on my machine up and running:

https://github.com/spring-petclinic/spring-petclinic-angularjs.git

I do everything step by step but struggle with the following command:

```
./mvnw clean install
```

Here, I get the following error message (see below the message for some more Details on my Setup):

```
Downloading https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/apache-maven/3.3.3/apache-maven-3.3.3-bin.zi
Exception in thread "main" java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.connect0(Native Method)
    at java.net.DualStackPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(DualStackPlainSocketImpl.java:69)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:339)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:200)
    at java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(AbstractPlainSocketImpl.java:182)
    at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:157)
    at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:391)
    at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:579)
    at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:618)
    at sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:160)
    at sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(NetworkClient.java:180)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:378)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(HttpClient.java:473)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(HttpsClient.java:270)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(HttpsClient.java:327)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:191)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(HttpURLConnection.java:931)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.java:177)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1299)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpsURLConnectionImpl.java:254)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.downloadInternal(DefaultDownloader.java:73)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.DefaultDownloader.download(DefaultDownloader.java:60)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.Installer.createDist(Installer.java:64)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.WrapperExecutor.execute(WrapperExecutor.java:121)
    at org.apache.maven.wrapper.MavenWrapperMain.main(MavenWrapperMain.java:50)
```

I am behind a Company Proxy, but everything on my system should be configured correctly to use it:

Eclipse has the Settings, Maven has the Settings in ist Settings.xml and also in my Git, I configured the Proxy using the following:

```
git config --global http.proxy [MYPROXY]:[PORT]
git config --global https.proxy [MYPROXY]:[PORT]
```

Comment: If you are behind a proxy be aware of eventually scanning time for the downloaded zip...may be you need to change the timeouts...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Meanwhile, I "solved" the problem by manually installing Apache Maven 3.3.3 and putting the installation paths bin-directory into my PATH-windows system environment variable. Also, instead of executing the mvnw command, I executed the mvn command.

```
./mvn clean install
```

It works, but is rather a quick and simple workaround than a solution.

Answer (score 2):

I've solved the same problem by adding proxy settings in mvnw.cmd by changing the following line:

```
%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS% %MAVEN_OPTS% %MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS% -classpath %WRAPPER_JAR% "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%" %WRAPPER_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CONFIG% %*
```

to

```
%MAVEN_JAVA_EXE% %JVM_CONFIG_MAVEN_PROPS% %MAVEN_OPTS% %MAVEN_DEBUG_OPTS% -classpath %WRAPPER_JAR% "-Dmaven.multiModuleProjectDirectory=%MAVEN_PROJECTBASEDIR%" "-Dhttp.proxyHost=myProxyServer" "-Dhttp.proxyPort=8080" "-Dhttps.proxyHost=myProxyServer" "-Dhttps.proxyPort=8080" %WRAPPER_LAUNCHER% %MAVEN_CONFIG% %*
```